# What is the suggested approach for command validation in Akka?

Tags: akka, cqrs, akka.net

Let’s say I have the following scenario. There is an UserActor. Besides trivial properties like Id, FirstName, LastName, user internal state contains a CategoryId, which represents user adherence to specific Category. The category itself is a separate domain entity which has properties by its own. To perform the operation of assignment user to specific category I have to make sure that the specific category actually exists. What is the proper way of dealing with this kind of scenarios, which guarantee system consistency?

I am thinking about two solutions, but I am not sure which is worse than the other.

1. Ignore rule “tell don’t ask”, and query CategoriesActor using Ask protocol to determine if category with specified Id exists or not?
2. Spawn some sort of auxiliary actor (ValidatorActor) which perform all the necessary validations and reply with result to UserActor. In the meantime, UserActor will change its state to sth like “Waiting for Command Results” and will be stacking all incoming messages up until proper command validation results arrive.

The first solution denies everything I believe. The second does not scale too good in terms of class/actors proliferation. Moreover, if UserActor is persistent FSM I have no idea how to go back from this “waiting for command validation results” limbo. There is no Unbecome equivalent for FSMs.

I believe if you use Akka together with CQRS/ES approach you should deal with this kind of issues. How did you address them? I have read a few books about Akka and haven’t found any opinionated approach. It’s strange because in my opinion, it is such a fundamental use case.

I would really appreciate any hints.

Comment: Why do you need to check for existence?

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu Because the selected category may be removed or broken in some other way in the meantime. For the record, the category is just an example of some external dependency which has to be checked before an event can be safely stored.

Comment: But the Category could at any time be deleted, after the user "adheres" to it. In other words, checking the external dependency existence is not the responsibility of the User actor; in this case, if you want to limit the number of times the system enters in an invalid state (like the one you want to prevent) you may query the CategoryActor before the Command gets executed and you won't break any rules. You should however note that this checking is done in an eventual consistency manner so it does not prevent invalid states, it only limits the number of times it happen; it will happen.

Comment: So you are saying I should build some kind of facade actor which handle the command, perform all the necessary validations and then route the message to appropriate UserActor?

Comment: I'm saying that you should design your system to recover from an "invalid" state instead of preventing it. You can also try to prevent it, in order to reject some bad client from messing with your data but only as an optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to prevent an invalid system state that could at any time happen. The Category could get at any time deleted, after the User adheres to it.

In the distributed world, preventing a *scalable* system to enter an invalid state is impossible. Instead, you should focus on how the system recovers from the invalid states. In this particular case, you should think about what should happen when (not if!) a Category gets deleted and there are Users that adhered to it. Maybe you notify them that the Category X does not exist any more or just removes their membership quietly? Your business people should tell you.

You may check for the existence of the Category *before* the User executes the command but only as an optimization, to limit the abusive users messing with your data for example, and not something that is at the heart of the system architecture.

> Ignore rule “tell don’t ask”, and query CategoriesActor using Ask protocol to determine if category with specified Id exists or not?

This rules does not applies here but in the situations where you ask the an Actor something and then tell the *same* Actor to do something based on what it told you.

P.S. I assumed that you have a distributed system because you chose to use the Actor model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But can elaborate a bit more?
1. What if my business people tell me that I should not allow removing Category when there are any users using it?
2. Are you saying that it is ok to use Ask to query some other actor and then decide what to do based on this information, in the caveat, that the actual work is conducted by querying actor, not the queried one?

Comment: @Hav then you don't use the Actor model but a strong consistent one. You should ask them what is the risk/impact when 1 in 999999 users may be in a deleted category for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly bend the rule of "tell, don't ask".  Akka.net's Receive and Command methods have an optional predicate called shouldHandle.  I do an `ask`, but do a `Sender.Tell()` inside the shouldHandle method.  If the result of the predicate is false, the action you specified will not be run.

Example code:

```
public MyActor
{
    Command<Object>(cmd => HandleObject(cmd), cmd => ValidateObject(cmd));
}

private bool ValidateObject(Object cmd)
{
    // Perform validation as necessary... isValid could be anything but needs to be set
    if(isValid)
    {
        Sender.Tell(true);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Sender.Tell(false);
        return false;
    }
}

private void HandleObject(Object cmd)
{
    // Handle command
}
```

In the code above, `HandleObject` will never be run unless `ValidateObject` returns true.  This pattern works for both `ask` and `tell`.  The only reason I do an `ask` is because I need to notify the user if the command fails validation... otherwise I would use `tell` without worrying about the doing `Sender.Tell`.